# accessing running application class from Another class

Tags: java, javafx

To Simplify i start 1 class, 1 class starts 2 class and 2 class need to change a value on 1 class without making a copy of 1 class.

Any help would be awesome

```
One Class{
int a;
    public static void main(string[] args) {
    Two two = new Two();
    }
}
Two Class{
    //need to be able to change int a undifined amount of times
}
```

Comment: The `Application` class is the entry point of the program. It doesn't really make sense to extend the class with multiple classes, unless you want to provide multiple entry points. You can use at most one of them though. If this is not needed, I recommend not extending `Application` and instead designing the class accoriding to your needs. (`Stage`s other than the initial one can be created using `new Stage()` btw.)

Comment: ahhhh, yea well i want 2 application frames, both kinda need to extend application, and digging thro api is rough, i would assume theres a way to have 2 frames/applications, that can interact, and why is it that the application class is the only entry point. i know theres a way around this, like look at blender where its stuffed with like 12 windows sometimea

Comment: `Application` is not the _only_ entry point of JavaFX but it is the "proper" entry point. And there should only be one `Application` per, well... application. As fabian mentions, you can create other `Stage`s yourself and display content in them. Using this you can have many windows open; they all belong to the one application though. As for intercommunication, if `One` creates `Two` and `Two` needs to modify `One`, just pass the instance of `One` to the instance of `Two` when created or shortly after. Either that or communicate through a shared model.

Comment: So i make i application three that holds class one and two of which both extend from class three and have the world object in class three and super within class one and Two ??? (Fyi world is the variable that both classes need access to while both are running, a shared variable)

Comment: oh wait, so i start Two windows within one Application, using stage, hmmmmm, i need to look into Stage.... SO i justed looked at the api and i can see i have some reading todo, Thank You!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! everyone

Comment: Alright So I Found a link That answers my question just darn perfectly.https://hajsoftutorial.com/javafx-tutorial/javafx-creating-multiple-stage/

Answer (score 0):

Uh this is the answer to my Question. originally i had different code posted that extended application, and i just had no idea what a stage was. And thanks to Thoses who delt with this dummy, lolz

https://hajsoftutorial.com/javafx-tutorial/javafx-creating-multiple-stage/